# Visual Studio 2015 community edition installation location

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install the Community edition of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 on a friend's machine (Windows 10). However, during the installation wizard, I'm not able to change the installation location (it's grayed out).

Does anyone know whether the Community edition allows the user to change the default installation location? And if it does, what am I missing?

Comment: It may allow only selecting install locations for some parts of it, but if there has been a previous installation some others may also be grayed out. In general it's quite hard to install it to any other location than default. If it's due to disk space, a junction might be useful. It might still check for disk space and not install though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sami already hinted, there were indeed some left overs of a previous Visual Studio installation. However, for some reason, they didn't show up in the 'Uninstall a program'-list of the control panel. After using a software removal tool (Revo Uninstaller), we managed to get rid of these remaining components (.NET packages). After that, we could change the default installation location again.